# Maven archetype strips comments

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I'm using Maven to generate an archetype. I'm able to get the archetype to generate fine and the project template it generates works as expected. The only problem is in my shell scripts. Anything commented out in the script gets stripped leaving behind only commands. I've searched high and low and all I've been able to find was another user facing a similar issue with java comments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797333/maven-archetype-generation-is-stripping-java-comments That question remains unanswered, so I figure I'll ask again. Does anyone know why Maven archetypes strip comments or how to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the #set command itself to set a #hash variable equal to "#" worked, allowing me to maintain shell comments in scripts generated by the archetype. This can get relatively ugly when using 80 # symbols in a row in a header, but that's another matter...

Answer (score 3):

I also had a similar problem with hashes. On page http://johnjianfang.blogspot.com/2009/03/escape-properties-in-maven-archetypes.html I found answer.

Something like this works fine in my case:

```
#set($hash = '#')
${hash}
```

Output:

```
#
```

Answer (score 2):

Maven uses [Apache Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html) to perform substitutions/replacements when copying your archetype's template files to the project locations.  The '#' character is used to begin directives, e.g. `#set`, in Velocity.  My guess is that Velocity doesn't recognize your comment as a valid directive and silently deletes it during the replacement process.

Though I haven't verified this works - I would try escaping the comments with using a backslash (\) as defined in Velocity's [user manual](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#escapingvalidvtlreferences) to solve the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. In fact, using the backslash as an escape character caused an escape effect for the following shell commands leaving me with a blank script. It seems that the comments were still stripped out and the escape characters applied to the following lines.

Additionally, this wouldn't explain the other user's issue in the question I linked to since java comments don't use the '#' character. It seems to me as though ALL comments get ignored. I'll take a look deeper into Velocity and see where that gets me.

Comment: While escaping didn't work, using the #set command itself to set a #hash variable equal to "#" worked, allowing me to maintain shell comments in scripts generated by the archetype.

Comment: Now that you mention it - I dug in my bookmarks and found [this blog post](http://johnjianfang.blogspot.com/2009/03/escape-properties-in-maven-archetypes.html) describing a similar technique for keeping variables in the scripts.  Perhaps you should add your solution as an answer to this question and accept it as correct.

Comment: Worked for me. Looks like only some files are affected. I found '#' in an xml file were being stripped invalidating the xml file. Added #set($hash = '#') at the top of the file and replaced the # characters with the variable ${hash}.