# How to use custom delimiter when creating filtered fileSets in a maven artefact?

Tags: java, maven, serverless, maven-archetype

I'm trying to create a custom maven artefact that creates a basic Java Handler for AWS Lambda. One of the files in my `archetype-resources` is a [`serverless.yml`](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/) file as we are looking to deploy this handler using the [ServerLess Framework](https://serverless.com/). I want this file to be part of a `filtered=true` `fileSet` as I want to pre-populate certain fields based on the project groupId, projectId etc. Here's a sample:

```
service: cmpy-prefix-${groupId}-${artifactId}-service

# exclude the code coverage files and circle ci files
package:
  exclude:
  - coverage/**
  - .circleci/**

...

profider:
  ...
  environment:
    S3_BUCKET_NAME: ${self:provider.stage}-cmpy-bkt
```

And I add this file to `src/main/resources/META-INF/maven/archetype-metadata.xml` as follows:

```
<fileSet encoding="UTF-8" filtered="true" packaged="false">
    <directory></directory>
    <includes>
        <include>serverless.yml</include>
    </includes>
</fileSet>
```

Now my problem is that `serverless.yml` file contains `${self:provider.stage}` which interfere's when I run `maven:generate` for this archetype and the error I get is:

`org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException: Encountered ":provider.stage}-cmpy-bkt\...`

I tried to set the `<delimiter>` for the `maven-resource-plugin` in the `pom.xml` for my main archetype to no avail. Essentially, I added the following to the pom of the archetype project:

```
    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${org.apache.maven.plugins.maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <addDefaultExcludes>false</addDefaultExcludes>
                <delimiters>$[*]</delimiters>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

But I still face the same problem when I try to generate a new project using this archetype. The maven archetype plugin seems to be ignoring the delimiter.

Any advice/help on how I can fix this will be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I had not realised I could add Velocity directives in my archetype files. 
See this other Stackoverflow post for hints [Maven archetype strips comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934732/maven-archetype-strips-comments)